# Select next highlighted row in a gridview

Tags: c#, gridview

Here is my current code:

```
private void searchBtn_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    //get the search term from the textbox
    String searchTerm = textBox.Text;
    //if the column index is 1 the we search by code and 2 if we search by name
    int columnIndex = 0;
    if (codeRadioBtn.Checked)
        columnIndex = 1;
    else
        columnIndex = 2;

    gridView.ClearSelection();

    int firstIndex = 0;
    bool found = false;
    for (int i = 0; i < gridView.Rows.Count; i++)
    {
        //change background color to DarkOrange for the rows that contain the searched value
        if (gridView.Rows[i].Cells[columnIndex].Value.ToString().Contains(searchTerm, StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase))
        {
            //gridView.Rows[i].Selected = true;
            gridView.Rows[i].DefaultCellStyle.BackColor = Color.DarkOrange;
            found = true;

            if (firstIndex < 1)
            {
                firstIndex = i;
            }
        }
    }
    //display message if no item was found
    if (!found)
        MessageBox.Show("The search term was not found", "Warning");
    else
    // scroll grid to first highlighted row
    this.gridView.Rows[firstIndex].Cells[0].Selected = true;
    this.gridView.CurrentCell = this.gridView.Rows[firstIndex].Cells[0];
    this.gridView.FirstDisplayedCell = this.gridView.CurrentCell;
}
```

I am trying to make it, onClick of the search button a second time it will set the current selected to the next highlighted row.

I have been trying for a while and can't figure it out. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: You really need to reword your question. It isn't clear what you are asking.What is the question? What are you trying to achieve? It would seem to me you are trying to create a search function, and when pressed it highlights all the rows that match your search. Then if pushed again you want the current row to be the next matched term?

Comment: Yes, I am sorry Dan, that is exactly what I am trying to accomplish. When searched I was all the found strings to be highlighted and sets the active cell to the first found, which works fine. I want it to also, when the search button is clicked again, jump to the next found string. Does that make more sense?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use a `List` or `Array` to store all matches.

```
 List<int> matchList = new List<int>();
```

e.g.

Whilst you are highlighting the rows, why not also add that row into a list.

```
gridView.Rows[i].DefaultCellStyle.BackColor = Color.DarkOrange;
matchList.add(i);
```

To work out whether it is the first click i.e. to load and highlight matches set a int outside of the button click to keep track of how many times you clicked the button.

```
 int clickcount= 0;
```

Then after you have found and highlighted set clickcount to 1 and make sure you don't highlight again using an if statement, but instead run the below loop.

```
if (clickcount != 0 && clickcount !=matchList.Count-1)
{

     this.gridView.CurrentCell = this.gridView.Rows[clickcount].Cells[0];

 clickcount++;
}
else
{
clickcount = 0;
}
```

**Full Example**

```
  int clickcount = 0;
    List<int> matchList = new List<int>();

    protected void searchBtn_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (clickcount == 0)
        {
            //get the search term from the textbox
            String searchTerm = textBox.Text;
            //if the column index is 1 the we search by code and 2 if we search by name
            int columnIndex = 0;
            if (codeRadioBtn.Checked)
                columnIndex = 1;
            else
                columnIndex = 2;

            gridView.ClearSelection();

            int firstIndex = 0;
            bool found = false;

            for (int i = 0; i < gridView.Rows.Count; i++)
            {
                //change background color to DarkOrange for the rows that contain the searched value
                if (gridView.Rows[i].Cells[columnIndex].Value.ToString().Contains(searchTerm, StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase))
                {
                    //gridView.Rows[i].Selected = true;


                    this.gridView.CurrentCell = gridView.Rows[0].Cells[0];
                    gridView.Rows[i].DefaultCellStyle.BackColor = Color.DarkOrange;
                    matchList.Add(i);
                    found = true;

                    if (firstIndex < 1)
                    {
                        firstIndex = i;
                    }
                }
            }
            //display message if no item was found 
            if (!found)
            {
                MessageBox.Show("The search term was not found", "Warning");
            }
           //add one to the count to stop the search happing again.
            clickcount = 1;
        }
        else
        {
            //if clickcount = 1+ or your've reached the end of your match list count
              if (clickcount != 0 && clickcount != matchList.Count - 1)
            {


                //gridView.Rows[clickcount].DefaultCellStyle.BackColor = Color.Red;
                this.gridView.CurrentCell = gridView.Rows[matchList[clickcount]].Cells[0];

                clickcount++;
            }
            else
              {
                  MessageBox.Show("No More Found");
                clickcount = 0;
                matchList.Clear();
            }

        }
    }
```

Comment: I finally got a chance to try your suggestion, and that sounds amazing but i can't seem to get it to work. It gives me an error at build CS1061 

"List<int>' does not contain a definition for 'count' and no extension method method count accepting a first argument of type List<int> can be found (are you missing a using directive or and assembly reference?)"

Comment: It's not that you've copy and pasted my spelling mistake in the word "count" is it? The count should be with an uppercase C. i.e "list.Count"

Comment: that was the problem for the build error, cant believe i didnt catch that.. But I still cant get it to work. It now highlights the searched for terms, but does not move to them or the next one.

Comment: So first click you want it to find and highlight all matches, then every click after you want it to cell selected to change to the next match?

Comment: Yes. When you click the search button the first time, it highlights all found strings and scrolls to the first found. Then every click after that will scroll to the next in the list.

Comment: Yes it does make sense, but I still cant get it to scroll to the first highlighted, or the next ones after. It just highlights them all and thats it at the moment

Comment: Have you nested your existing code into an if statement with the loop I wrote as the else?

Comment: like this? [link](http://pastebin.com/Huuga7ra) Sorry for my issues, I am pretty new to C# coding in general. This was my first program in it.

Comment: when i try that code i get "An unhandled exception of type 'System.InvalidOperationException' occurred in System.Windows.Forms.dll

Additional information: Cell provided already belongs to a grid. This operation is not valid."

Comment: when i debug and click the search button the second time that error shows

Comment: GIve me 2 mins. I'll have a look at your full code in my IDE.

Comment: ive tried that and it throws _____An unhandled exception of type 'System.InvalidOperationException' occurred in System.Windows.Forms.dll

Additional information: Cell provided already belongs to a grid. This operation is not valid._____

on first Search

Comment: It doesnt show a line that has the error, so I am not sure

Comment: copied, you can delete now

Comment: @Beltian, Added new snippet.

Comment: Good luck with your project.